# Undefined variable in .then() function

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm writing a Protractor test that should interact with a slider bar. The slider bar controls a field that outputs a dollar value. The test attempts to move the bar along the x-axis until the value of $15,000 is returned.

I've managed to get the slider moving, but it doesn't respect the limit set by the amount variable. Asynchronous commands make my life harder.

```
var dragSlider = function(amount) {
    element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text)
        if (text !== amount) {
            browser.actions().dragAndDrop(element(by.css('.irs-slider.single')), {x:1, y:0}).perform();
            element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText().then(console.log(amount, text, amount===text)).then(dragSlider());
        }
    });
};
```

When I run `dragSlider("$15,000");`, the `console.log(amount, text, amount===text)` returns, e.g., the following:

```
$14,900
undefined '$14,900' false
$15,000
undefined '$15,000' false
$15,100
undefined '$15,100' false
```

Could you please let me know what it is that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, `dragSlider()` is calling your function with an `undefined` `amount`. So what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, All. @Bergi's right. Silly omission on my part! Corrected code below.

```
var dragSlider = function(amount) {
    element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText().then(function(text) {
        if (text !== amount) {
            browser.actions().dragAndDrop(element(by.css('.irs-slider.single')), {x:1, y:0}).perform();
            dragSlider(amount);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: The line `element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText().then(dragSlider(amount));` is doing nothing except calling `dragSlider(amount)`.

Comment: If you're trying to pass the `text` from `getText` into `dragSlider` you'll want to look at my example above.

Comment: @rrowland. Thanks for pointing out the redundant code. I did just need to call dragSlider(amount) without passing the text. I've revised the code above. Apologies if the original question was too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `console.log()` immediately rather than passing it to the `Promise.then()` callback.

Try changing:

```
element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText(text)
  .then(console.log(amount, text, amount===text))
  .then(dragSlider(text));
```

To:

```
element(by.css('.irs-single')).getText().then(dragSlider);
```